# door locks locking and unlocking problems

Tags: jeep, locks, fob, commander

I have a 2007 jeep commander, when I unlock my doors using my fob sometimes it will  unlock and then lock right away but not always. its a guessing game when it will happen.

Comment: Do you have a spare fob? If so does the same thing happen with it?

Comment: Is one of the doors slightly ajar?  Some cars do strange things when this situation exists.